# Display mathematical formula in pdf using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

How to display complex mathematical formula in pdf using iText JAVA API.

`Requirement is just like following formula in image.`

[image]

Comment: The layouting capabilities of iText are more targeted at normal text. While it surely is possible to also layout mathematical formula using iText, chances are that using a scientific typesetting system with the option of PDF output (like many LaTeX systems) is easier

Comment: Is it possible to know where to find some examples about displaying mathematicals formulas using IText 7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we can do is insert created image for the complex formula like following example.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class AddImage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("sample.pdf"));
            document.open();
            Image img = Image.getInstance("formula.gif");
            img.scaleToFit(200f, 200f);
            document.add(img);
            document.close();
            System.out.println("That's it");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception : " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

That's it...